# How do I get into the Jawa's Sandcrawler

Tags: star-wars-jedi-knight-jedi-academy

I'm replaying Star Wars: Jedi Academy, and I'm stuck on one of the first missions. It's the Tattooine mission to retrieve the droid from the Jawa's Sandcrawler. [I'm pretty sure I got stuck here last time too. I can't remember what I did.]

I've reached the Sandcrawler and cleared out all the Tuskan Raiders. There was a switch on the second balcony that I pulled, but I didn't see what it did because there was one last Tuskan Raider shooting at me when I pulled it.

There's a door on the third balcony that I can't reach, and a door on the outside of the Sandcrawler that is locked.

I've been running around using force sense, but I can't "see" anything. What am I missing? How do I get inside the Jawa's Sandcrawler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I restarted from a previous checkpoint because I felt bad about taking my frustration out on innocent Jawas. But it turns out there is an elevator in the back corner behind a minecart.

The lever unlocks the elevator, and you can reach it if you force pull the cart out of the way. Then the elevator brings you up to the third balcony where the door is.